# How to listen socket TCP/IP in AndroidAsync?

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

I use library [AndroidAsync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync) in my project.

I try to connect to socket server by IP/Port.

For this exist function:

```
AsyncHttpClient.getDefaultInstance().websocket()
```

Function `websocket` takes two arguments, first link on the request object, second is callback string.

Comment: add a bit more code and clarify the question. It appears from your description that the callback will be invoked each time there is a connection attempted, it's not a classic 'listen' loop.